# PostgresSQL . Permission Denied in cmd when I reading from sql with \i

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

The Problem

**With Quotation**

```
postgres-# \i 'G:\\postgres\person.sql'
G:/postgresperson.sql: No such file or directory
postgres-#
```

I am using windows 10. I changed folder permission to "Everyone" in the properties. I copied the sql file path and paste it to the cmd. But it still saying permission denied. I have this problem even without quotation.

**Without quotation**

```
postgres-# \i G:\\postgres\person.sql
G:: Permission denied
postgres-#
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Try forward slashes `\i g:/postgres/person.sql`

Comment: The permission issue may also be caused by the permission of the postgres user or the windows user. Try to open the terminal with administrator privileges. Finally you can see that the location is not correct in the no such file error. It says: G:/postgresperson.sql but it must be G:/postgres/person.sql So may be you can also try like \i 'G:\\postgres\\person.sql'  (with two back slashes \\\)

Comment: Thanks all of you for saving my sanity. Both solutions worked.